# Error in Feature selection with Recursive feature elimination in random forest model

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

I have some hundred samples and I have already classified them into four different classes (clusters). Now, I'm interested in identifying the best set of genes that classify the samples into different classes.

I want to apply randomforest with recursive feature elimination and detect the genes (features). My data looks like below. Just posting some example data here.

[image]

Above data is just an example: My original data is in dataframe `df` with 100 samples in first column and 4 classes in second column and columns 3 to column 1002 there are in total 1000 genes with expression values.

I'm using the below code but I see there is an error.

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(Hmisc)
library(randomForest)

# define the control using a random forest selection function
control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)

# run the RFE algorithm
results <- rfe(df[,3:1002], df[,2], sizes = df[,1:1002], rfeControl=control)
```

There is an Error: And I feel that I'm doing wrong somewhere.

```
Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection
```

Here I'm giving the `dput` of the above data.

```
df <-structure(list(Samples = structure(c(1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample10", "Sample11", "Sample12", "Sample13", "Sample14", "Sample15", 
"Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7", 
"Sample8", "Sample9"), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Class1", 
"Class2", "Class3", "Class4"), class = "factor"), Gene1 = c(1.030078784, 
0.944152632, 0.140700452, 0.013432323, 0.265233165, -0.084496727, 
4.835469554, 0.089434913, -0.433436179, 1.462895475, -0.116005356, 
1.007868422, 0.244881864, -1.495666899, 0.364368654), Gene2 = c(1.407236415, 
1.229003431, -0.322221459, -1.361955252, 0.310963955, 0.80115063, 
4.27765356, 0.872413223, -0.568249851, 1.187873069, -0.255284575, 
1.878058722, -0.767371822, -0.859697473, 0.057304769), Gene3 = c(0.200772234, 
-0.048349737, 1.224274924, 0.492396142, 0.500786902, -0.731802706, 
1.853246564, 1.611995455, 0.287088678, 0.509235514, 2.031735375, 
3.074950771, 2.069407179, 0.886158642, 1.736798303), Gene4 = c(1.23309207, 
1.321282889, 2.403301108, 0.748860637, 1.019200751, 1.393254607, 
2.667976275, 1.158136576, 1.89503732, 2.178257717, 0.747697632, 
2.834410716, 0.028594536, -0.411039831, 1.100167946), Gene5 = c(0.883005616, 
0.570786704, 0.72649548, 4.705893892, 0.086345885, 0.502530136, 
2.681497202, 0.640362079, 0.327319762, 2.086767741, 1.853085301, 
1.001799748, 0.126208601, 0.911621722, 0.671191951), Gene6 = c(2.590519025, 
3.076688902, 1.77414005, 1.014363629, 1.134652225, 2.71957962, 
4.696379063, -0.301828123, 1.214261665, 2.413881644, -0.470794827, 
0.520494891, 0.194511306, 0.075331863, 2.315680177), Gene7 = c(0.088929673, 
0.472549468, -0.125630236, -0.069648505, -0.715250242, 0.068554966, 
4.131662998, -0.075265565, -1.234425917, 0.343350342, 0.190414782, 
1.153495806, 0.210317581, -0.475603641, 0.294299351), Gene8 = c(2.112231178, 
2.780100532, 2.423828553, 1.569215682, 1.018119196, 2.583413401, 
6.483053565, 2.215201821, 1.893325529, 2.342058862, 4.001423142, 
4.221704757, 1.978211867, 1.452633851, 2.556589741)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can use the above data and apply random forest to know which genes classify the samples into different classes. thanq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sizes refer to the number of features you would like to try and retain, it should numeric but you provided something weird in `df[,1:1002]`.

See something like below, where i simulate a dataset and setting the sizes correctly ensures it runs along to choose the optimal number of features (from what you provide):

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(Hmisc)
library(randomForest) 

set.seed(101)
df = data.frame(samples=paste0("Samples",1:99),
                Class=paste0("Class",rep(1:3,33)),
                matrix(rnorm(99*1000),ncol=1000))

colnames(df)[3:ncol(df)]=paste0("Gene",1:1000)

# we create like 100 informative genes for Class1 and Class2
df[df$Class=="Class1",3:103] = df[df$Class=="Class1",3:103] + rpois(33*100,1.5)
df[df$Class=="Class2",104:203] = df[df$Class=="Class2",104:203] + rpois(33*100,1.5)

control <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=2)

# run the RFE algorithm
results <- rfe(df[,3:1002], df[,2], sizes = c(50,100,200), 
               rfeControl=control)
```

From the above, I ask for 50,100 or 200 informative features and I get:

```
results
Recursive feature selection

Outer resampling method: Cross-Validated (2 fold) 

Resampling performance over subset size:

 Variables Accuracy  Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
        50   0.9792 0.9688    0.02946 0.04419         
       100   0.9896 0.9844    0.01473 0.02210         
       200   1.0000 1.0000    0.00000 0.00000        *
      1000   1.0000 1.0000    0.00000 0.00000         

The top 5 variables (out of 200):
   Gene94, Gene198, Gene137, Gene136, Gene158

> results$optsize
[1] 200
```

Comment: thanq very much for the reply. sorry I am a bit confused and have some doubts. So here `sizes` is where you asked for the most informative genes. And the `results` show `*` in the `selected`. What does it mean? And how do I get which genes lead to  classify the samples into different classes?

Comment: Yes, so with sizes, you try 50, 100 or 200 genes... Based on the accuracy compared to the full dataset, rfe tells you to go with 200 genes, because it's almost as good as using 1000 genes. You get the genes by doing results$optVariables

Comment: You can see with 50 genes, you have an accuracy of 0.9696, 100, 0.9898 and 200 you get something close to what you get with 1000, so it makes sense to use 200 right? of course this example is a bit rigged (because I simulated it so), but with your actual dataset, you should see this pattern with different sizes, if there are truly informative features

Comment: Yes, I understood now. small doubt again. so this 200 genes lead to which class among the four classes?

Comment: It can be used to separate the 3 classes, because in the random forest, you specified 3 classes. If you want to know the genes that discriminate each class, you have to set it up as a binary instead, for example, class1 versus others, class2 versus others etc..

Comment: Most likely it will give you the same results, so I suggest you take these say 200 genes and just see their values or strengths in the different classes. This will tell you which classes it is useful for

Comment: Ok. when I tried running on one of my dataset I see the `Error` again. Dataset has `1261` columns. `dim(df)` is `60 1261`. first column is with sample names. Second column is with 4 classes. From 3rd column to 1261 column its genes with expression data. So I used this command. `results <- rfe(df[,3:1261], df[,2], sizes = c(50,100,200), rfeControl=control)` And the Error is `Error in summary.connection(connection) : invalid connection`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208243/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-beginner).